# mysql_field_type differentiate between varchar and text

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the datatype of a column, but both varchar and text datatypes both return the value 'string' under the mysql_field_type function in php.

Is there a better, more specific method of checking a columns datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always run a `SHOW COLUMNS IN your_table` query (via the regular `mysql_query()` function), which gives you details on the table's columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are in wrong, mysql_field_type function in php does not return 'string' for the 'text' datatype, but 'blob'.